# validates_numericality_of in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to set a range on the integer input on my two columns. I have;

```
def change
  add_column :stores, :min_order_time, :integer, default: 0
  add_column :stores, :max_order_time, :integer, default: 60
  validate :min_order_time, :greater_than_or_equal_to 0
  validate :max_order_time, :greater_than_or_equal_to 30
end
```

I get;
    undefined method `validates'

I switched to the `validate` method and started using `:greater_than_or_equal_to` because this wasn't working;

```
add_column :stores, :min_order_time, :integer, default: 0
add_column :stores, :max_order_time, :integer, default: 60

validates_numericality_of :min_order_time, :in => 0..20
validates_numericality_of :max_order_time, :in => 30..90
```

The error I got was

```
undefined method `validates_numericality_of' for #....
```

I am using Ruby v2.2.0 so this [`validates_numericality_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_numericality_of) should be valid, right?

I have included this in model for good measure, but didn't help;

```
 include ActiveModel::Validations
```

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yes. Felt a little foolish that I didn't put it in the model. I'm very new to Ruby.

Comment: Everyone has started sometime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation should be put into the model, not migration:

```
class Store 
  validates_numericality_of :min_order_time, in: 0..20
  validates_numericality_of :max_order_time, in: 30..90
end
```

What you really want is [`inclusion`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of):

```
validates_inclusion_of :min_order_time, in: 0..20
```